# htaccess : wildcard folders and url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have some domain for example `http://domain.com`

```
http://domain.com/sport -> Folder actually exits

http://domain.com/sport/123/ - > Folder dont exist

http://domain.com/sport/123/hello.html - > file dont exist
```

So when `http://domain.com/sport/123/` or 
`http://domain.com/sport/123/hello.html` is visited..Instead of throwing not found error it must show the content of the first folders index.php , that is in this example it must show the contents of `http://domain.com/sport/index.php`

I tried below code.but it throws 500 internal error

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.*$ /$1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Look at your Apache error log to see what the cause of the 500 error is. I can't see anything syntactically invalid in that .htaccess clode.

Comment: i am doing via cpanel...can u please tell me how to check the apache error ?

Comment: No I can't. I have no idea how cpanel provides log access; you'll have to check your host's documentation.

Comment: You might remove the leading `/` in `/$1/index.php` to be `$1/index.php`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : no not working sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still get a 500 internal server error if you wrap all of your rewrite rules inside an `IfModule` container? E.G.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   # Turn mod_rewrite on
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.*$ /$1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you stop getting the error, but rewriting is still not working, that means you have to turn on the rewrite module. How this is done is entirely dependent on your setup, your hosting services setup, and/or whether you have access to the `httpd.conf` file.